# How can I get what element is being hovered using react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an unordered list with anchor (`<a>`) tags and I need to apply some style based on what link the mouse is hovering.

Is there a way for me to access the classes of the element that is being hovered?

Comment: Can you attach your html and javascript code you've tried?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to apply a style to an element on hover, use the `:hover` CSS selector...

```css
#mydiv:hover {
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<div id="mydiv">Text to hover on!</div>
```

If you can change the CSS only to get the style changes you want, that's ideal compared to using code to change the styles.  With a 100% CSS solution, there's other advantages....

- You can have people who only know CSS maintain and update the code.
- You can disable styles without disabling code.
- You can update styles without breaking code.
- A CSS checker will catch issues in a `.css` file that would be missed if they were encoded in raw JS.

Source: [**MDN Documentation - `:hover`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover)

Answer (score 0):

You can create an `Item` component that insides manages state to see if the rendered item is being hovered or not with the `onMouseEnter` and `onMouseLeave` functions. But since you are trying to modify the styling of the elements for such basic action as being hovered, you should keep with just CSS, targeting the HTML element with `:hover` selector.

In the first approach every `Item` component will have that state so then in the `style={}` you can do `style={isHovered ? {background: "red"} : null}` supposing you have an `isHovered` state.

I would recommend you [styled-components](https://styled-components.com/), they are great.

Answer (score 0):

In ReactJS the events have name like `onMouseOver`, you can see other events [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html?#mouse-events).

For your case you can write like below:

```js
<a onMouseOver={() => { console.log('hovered') }}> ~~~
```